# Calculate difference between two non-adjacent rows

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I calculate time difference between two rows in a table, based on a value in another field in the table.
Table (simplified) look like;

```
Unit  Date              Status
0001  17.11.2017 09:52  INSPECTED
0001  17.11.2017 09:48  CLEAN
0001  17.11.2017 09:45  CLEANING
0001  17.11.2017 09:43  DIRTY
0001  16.11.2017 14:55  INSPECTED
0001  16.11.2017 14:54  CLEAN
0001  16.11.2017 12:54  CLEANING
0001  16.11.2017 12:22  DIRTY
0001  16.11.2017 12:20  CLEAN
0001  15.11.2017 10:48  CLEAN
0001  15.11.2017 10:27  CLEANING
0001  15.11.2017 09:03  DIRTY
```

Date field is of type DATE, Unit and Status values are from parent tables.

Based on a column Status, I have to calculate difference between status DIRTY and next status CLEAN, for each day and each unit. Example data should produce;

```
0001  17.11.2017  00:05
0001  16.11.2017  02:32
0001  15.11.2017  01:45
```

The query is the source for the chart in Oracle APEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a self join - you can use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```
SELECT unit,
       "Date",
       NUMTODSINTERVAL( Clean_date - "Date" =, 'DAY' ) AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD( CASE status WHEN 'CLEAN' THEN "Date" END )
           IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY unit --, TRUNC( "Date" )
                  ORDER BY "Date" ASC ) AS Clean_date
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE status = 'DIRTY';
```

Comment: FWIW, this could be made a little more performant by adding `where status in ('CLEAN', 'DIRTY')` to the subquery, since the OP doesn't appear to care about any other statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  SELECT a.unit,
         TRUNC (a.Date_t),
            TO_CHAR (
               EXTRACT (HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (a.Date_t - b.Date_t, 'DAY')),
               'FM00')
         || ':'
         || TO_CHAR (
               EXTRACT (
                  MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (a.Date_t - b.Date_t, 'DAY')),
               'FM00')
            diff
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM yourtable
           WHERE status = 'CLEAN') a
         JOIN (SELECT *
                 FROM yourtable
                WHERE status = 'DIRTY') b
            ON a.unit = b.unit AND TRUNC (a.Date_t) = TRUNC (b.Date_t)
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```